# Rails bootstrap corrupted

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, less, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I've got a weird problem. There was no problem until a few moments ago. Without changing anything to the less/css files (never), the appearance of bootstrap buttons and the navbar title have suddenly changed in their appearance. On the first picture you can see how the button should look like, on the second how it appears now, without hovering the mouse.

[image: How the buttons should look like]

[image: How it looks like now]

[image: How the title should look like]

[image]

Same with the navbar title, when I'm hovering the mouse, it inverts its colors. Does someone know what this is? Thanks a lot!

Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
#gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails"
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"

gem 'json'

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
    gem 'uglifier'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'therubyracer'

end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: Probably a typo in any of your layouts? What is the last thing you changed?

Comment: I was working on a table in a view. Can this occur even if I didn't change the css files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has happened to me when creating rails scaffolds in the console. The generator creates a scaffold stylesheet that overrides some of bootstrap's styles. I'm guessing this is what's happening.

Comment: Oh yes, this could be the problem. How did you fix it?

Comment: I removed the stylesheet generated by the scaffolding

Comment: Thanks a lot. I removed the app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss file and everything was ok again.